# Are my strawberries ok?

Tags: container-gardening, strawberries

I have strawberries on east facing balcony in a pot. I watered them with fertilizer mix and after that with normal water, every second day, they seem kind of dry but not completely

They have brown and black spots both on leaves from both sides and on stems. There are few berries, one getting red now, and flowers that look nice.

I'm located in north part of Croatia for the climate.

Are they ok? Should I be worried about different color? What can I do to get most of them, in both fruit and healthy long life of the plant?

[image: Strawberry leaves]
[image: Strawberry leaves below]
[image: Strawberry stems]

Comment: Hi Affaltar, one plant per question please, you can edit your question and ask new ones so we can help you better

Comment: @kevinsky Thank you, I edited this one and will make new ones for the other plants